# Cannot successfully disconnect from remote machine using 'nohup' or 'screen'

Tags: bash, ssh, nohup, xterm

I am trying to do some work on a **remote machine** and disconnect without terminating the work. I have tried both `nohup` and `screen`, unfortunately it is not working out. After I type `exit` to logout my work also terminates immediately.

I am trying to run 108 simulations on a **remote machine**. For that purpose I have written a script named `batch.sh` which runs one simulation after the other until all 108 are done. The program that actually runs a simulation launches 5 programs in 5 different terminals (using `xterm -e`). I run `batch.sh` using:

`nohup bash batch.sh &`

As long as I am connected everything works just fine. If I disconnect and then reconnect to check whether everything is working as it should...no joy :(

Are there any caveats I am overlooking? Possibly because my program launches other programs in external terminals?

**UPDATE**

If I use the suggestions of adding `-oForwardX11=no` to `ssh` and unset `DISPLAY` before launching my script I get these errors:

`nohup: ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out`

In `nohup.out` I have these messages:

`xterm Xt error: Can't open display:`

`xterm:  DISPLAY is not set`

Comment: Question like this belong to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl is there an easy way to migrate? Or do I have to start a new question over there?

Comment: Once you have an answer, you have to flag your question for moderation attention to have it moved.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your script/program is trying to launch `xterm` on its own. These days many systems enable X11 forwarding for their SSH client by default - as a result the `DISPLAY` variable is set in your shell session but becomes invalid once you disconnect. Therefore, as long as you are connected to the remote system, the `xterm` processes can access the X server on your local machine through the SSH connection, but die once that connection is severed.

I have occasionally encountered the same issue with Java programs that use e.g. the Java AWT subsystem to generate image files, even when there is no actual graphical window. You should first see if your program will somehow adapt if there is no X server available. One option is to disable X11 forwarding with the `-oForwardX11=no` option to `ssh`:

```
$ ssh -oForwardX11=no user@server.host.name
```

You could also try unsetting the `DISPLAY` environment variable before starting your script and see what happens.

However, if your program is launching `xterm` windows indiscriminately then you'd have to make it e.g. use an output file on the server instead - by modifying it, if necessary. As an added advantage, you would get rid off the network load and timing overhead involved with forwarded X connections.

If you cannot change the way your program works and you do not actually care about the output in those `xterm` windows, then you could try launching a [virtual framebuffer X server](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb) on the remote system and have your script use that for `xterm`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions (`-oForwardsX11=no` and unsetting `DISPLAY`) but that did not work. `nohup` replies with *nohup: ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out*. In `nohup.out` I have these messages: *xterm Xt error: Can't open display:* and *xterm:  DISPLAY is not set*. Indeed my script is launching multiple `xterm`. I really need those.

Comment: @cfbaptista: see my update. TL;DR: Either modify your program to *not* start `xterm` sessions, or use a virtual X server...

Comment: I can modify my program however I do care about the `xterm` output. The output is used for logging. However I do not need to see the output while it is running. Only after it is done if something went wrong. Could you give some more info on what you intend to have me do?

Comment: @cfbaptista: in that case, you can just append the output to a file - probably more than one - instead of launching an `xterm`.